# C# Update Multiple textbox for one column?

Tags: c#, sql-update, oledb

I got 5 textboxes and one button on my Windowform , and it's display data from my access database file.

then i use update statement to update all the data key in into textbox1, textbox2, textbox3 and etc.

my update statement:

```
cmd = new oledbcommand("UPDATE Table2 SET BALANCE = ? " + " WHERE ID = ? ", con);
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("BALANCE", textbox5.text);
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("BALANCE", textbox6.text);
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("BALANCE", textbox7.text);
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("BALANCE", textbox8.text);
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("BALANCE", textbox9.text);
```

cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("ID", textbox10.text)

but it's failed with no error.

So i tried another mehod

```
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("BALANCE", textbox5.text + textbox6.text + textbox7.text + textbox8.text + textbox9.text );
```

and all the value i input go into textbox5. any method can i solve this?

Sorry, im new..hopefully you're understand my problem.

**EDIT**

```
I tried to cmd = new oledbcommand("UPDATE Table2 SET BALANCE = ? ", con);
    cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("BALANCE", textbox5.text);
    cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("BALANCE", textbox6.text);
    cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("BALANCE", textbox7.text);
    cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("BALANCE", textbox8.text);
    cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("BALANCE", textbox9.text);
```

I put different number to different textbox, after that i preview the data, all the data value are the same...

Comment: according to your sql query you only update balance field

Comment: I display all the data from balance... how can i update multiple textbox to balance?

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("BALANCE", textbox5.text +","+ textbox6.text  +","+ textbox7.text  +","+ textbox8.text  +","+ textbox9.text );
```

and when you want to use them split by `,`

Comment: It's work, but all the value go to textbox5.text.... that i input from textbox5 - 10

Comment: when you display get value in `BALANCE` field and split it by `,` and display values

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. textbox1 value will display on textbox1, textbox2 value will display on textbox2 and so on. I dont want to merge in textbox1.
For Example, in my form, i got
BOOK         BALANCE
BOOK A        80
BOOK B        70
BOOK C        60

Comment: Let me get this straight are you trying to display how many line of your database? What you are describing is to put concatenate 5 values in to one row of your table, or to put 5 distinct rows each with the value the BALANCE column?

Comment: @Paciente8159 , Ok on my access database i got 2 column which is Book and Balance, and i got 5 row which to put book name and balance of the book, at my Window form i display balance of all book into different textbox (textbox1 - 5), and this is allow user to update.

Comment: In that case I don't think what you're trying to do is possible (like this at least). Data binding refers to one row of the datatable at the time. To do that you'll have to add different BindingContext for each Book/Balance pair of controls. You would do better with DataGridView control. Check MSDN for [Control.BindingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bindingcontext.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var totalBalance = Convert.ToDouble(Textbox1.Text) +  Convert.ToDouble(Textbox2.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(Textbox3.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(Textbox4.Text) +  Convert.ToDouble(Textbox5.Text) ;

cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("BALANCE", totalBalance);
```